# TYPO3 name of language file?

Tags: html, xml, file, typo3, typo3-extensions

So I'm currently working myself through the following introduction about extension developement for TYPO3:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/9.5/en-us/4-FirstExtension/4-make-products-persistent.html

There it says

> TYPO3 is able to group all records of an extension in the new record wizard. To define the name of this group, create a language file in the directory EXT:store_inventory/Resources/Private/Language/ and add the key extension.title.

What do I therefore have to name the language file (you might also want to check the link) for it to work and what exactly is meant by "add the key extension.title"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filenames of language files are created with several patterns

---

**`typo3conf/ext/extkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf`**

Is used in Backend i.e. for displaying the name of the tables, names of fields in the backend edit form, plugins etc. Naming convention here is rather strict. i.e.:

```xml
<trans-unit id="tx_extkey_domain_model_yourmodel.name">
    <source>Name</source>
</trans-unit>
```

can be used in the TCA of your model like:

```php
'name' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:extkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_extkey_domain_model_yourmodel.name',
    'config' => [...],
],
```

---

**`typo3conf/ext/extkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf`**

Is used in FrontEnd, so for an instance

```xml
<trans-unit id="my_list_header">
    <source>This is list of my elephants</source>
</trans-unit>
```

can be accessed within your Fluid template like

```html
<h1><f:translate key="my_list_header"/></h1>
```

*Note:* as you can see naming convention for id/key, in this case, is more flexible, then in case of *_db.xlf files.

---

**`typo3conf/ext/extkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh_tx_extkey_domain_model_yourmodel.xlf`**

Is for adding [CSH - Content Sensitive Help](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContextSensitiveHelp/Index.html)

```xml
<trans-unit id="name.description">
    <source>That's just the record's name Sherlock!</source>
</trans-unit>
```

In Backend looks like:
[image: CSH in BE]

You can also add *`[fieldname]`*.`details` node to XLIFF file and then it will allow displaying more detailed help for the field in the popup window.

```xml
<trans-unit id="name.details" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Sherlock Holmes (/ˈʃɜːrlɒk ˈhoʊmz/ or /-ˈhoʊlmz/) is a fictional private detective created by British author Sir Arthur Conan Doyle.</source>
</trans-unit>
```

---

***TIP***

Although learning of creating TYPO3 extensions from the scratch is quite romantic I'd suggest starting from installing [`extension_builder`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder/) extension and creating own extension's skeleton within minutes or even seconds. It will create most of the required elements, like SQL insertion, language files, TCA and TypoScript configuration files and many more, so you can investigate it against tutorial easier.

***About the key***

I may be wrong, just don't remember now, probably `extention.title` was some approach in a pre-Extbase way, years ago. Nowadays I didn't meet it in any extension which works with ver 9.x or 10.x. It's obviously missing part in documentation you mentioned in yor question and it should be rather fixed there, to be more detailed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and help. Since the explanations on the docs.typo3.org website are a bit overwhelming I will follow your advice and try to find a good tutorial on the extension builder. The reason I switched to this one is that I was working with an Udemy beginners tutorial about the extension builder. But that one was so badly done that I switched to this written version.

Comment: Just install it and start creating your own samples, you'll realize fast what's what. One tip about that, at the very beginning in domain modelling, click for the advanced mode in the upper right. If you at TYPO3 ver 10+ you'll need to get the current master from the GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought that your file should be **extention.title**

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought could maybe be it too. It only confused me that it's phrased so differently than the other times they said what title I should use. I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: If this helped you then please mark this as a solution. Cheers

Comment: There's no chance that file is named `extention.title` and it never was. Documentation mentions ***key*** which refers actually to ***id*** of the XLIFF node. However, it's some kind unfinished there.